# How to properly notify current view model about push notification when app is in background

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm developing a cellphone app for iOS and Android platforms using Xamarin and MvvmCross. In the Android version, I can receive push notifications while the app is in foreground and when the app is closed and navigate to the desired view model in these two cases.

I'm having problems to navigate to a specific view model from the splash screen when the app is in background and is resumed because user tapped in a push notification.

I could persist a flag and then check in every view model that is resumed if this flag is set and perform the navigation, but I don't really like the solution and would like to use events as I do when the app is in foreground. The problem is that when the app is in background and resumed from push notification, my events aren't still assigned to its handlers.

This is my code. SplashScreen:

```
public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenAppCompatActivity
{
    private bool _setPushNotificationHint;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _pushNotificationData;

    public SplashScreen() : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreenLayout)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            _pushNotificationData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                var value = Intent.Extras.Get(key);
                if(value != null)
                {
                    _pushNotificationData.Add(key, value.ToString());
                }                   
            }
            _setPushNotificationHint = true;
        }

        //avoid showing splash screen when resuming app pressing app icon or when tapping on push notification
        if (!IsTaskRoot)
        {
            //deliver notification only when app is started and is in background. When it's closed we'll use GetAppStartHint
            if (_setPushNotificationHint)
            {
                PushNotificationManager.OnMessageReceivedAppInBackground(this, _pushNotificationData);
            }
            Finish();
            return;
        }
        //just initialize essentials when first start of the app, not when splash screen is shown
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
    }
```

Here is where i get the push notification information and trigger my PushNotificationManager, that should fire the event. Here's an extract of it:

```
public class PushNotificationManager : IPushNotification
{
    public const string controlIdKey = "controlId";

    private static PushNotificationDataEventHandler _onNotificationReceived;
    public event PushNotificationDataEventHandler OnNotificationReceived
    {
        add
        {
            _onNotificationReceived += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _onNotificationReceived -= value;
        }
    }

    private static PushNotificationDataEventHandler _onNotificationReceivedWhileForeground;
    public event PushNotificationDataEventHandler OnNotificonReceivedWhileForegroundationReceived
    {
        add
        {
            _onNotificationReceivedWhileForeground += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _onNotificationReceivedWhileForeground -= value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles an incoming push notification in Android when app is in Foreground.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="remoteMessage">User info.</param>
    public static void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        var notification = CreateNotificationFromRemoteMessage(remoteMessage);
        _onNotificationReceivedWhileForeground?.Invoke(CrossPushNotification.Instance, new PushNotificationDataEventArgs(notification));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When app is in background in Android, we get to the splashscreen, who will call this method to publish a NotificationMessage to the interested ViewModels
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">Parameters.</param>
    public static void OnMessageReceivedAppInBackground(object sender, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var notification = CreateNotificationFromIntentExtras(parameters);
        //we need to publish a message instead of rising an event because this is triggered from the splash screen and the view model 
        //Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Publish(notificationMessage);
        //_onNotificationReceived?.Invoke(CrossPushNotification.Instance, new PushNotificationDataEventArgs(notification));
        //todo find a way to properly notify the current view to navigate to the device details view model
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// In Android plataform, we create the notification from the parameters received in the splashscreen as intent extras
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The notification from intent extras.</returns>
    /// <param name="parameters">Parameters.</param>
    private static Notification CreateNotificationFromIntentExtras(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        parameters.TryGetValue(controlIdKey, out var controlId);

        return new Notification
        {
            ControlId = controlId
        };
    }
```

Then in the BaseViewModel.cs I attach the handler of the events that should be fired from the PushNotificationManager:

```
public override void ViewAppeared()
    {
        base.ViewAppeared();
        //_token = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Subscribe<NotificationMessage>(OnNotificaitonMessage);
        CrossPushNotification.Instance.OnNotificationReceived += NotificationReceived;
        CrossPushNotification.Instance.OnNotificonReceivedWhileForegroundationReceived += NotificationInForegroundReceived;
    }

    public override void ViewDisappeared()
    {
        base.ViewDisappeared();
        //Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Unsubscribe<NotificationMessage>(_token);
        CrossPushNotification.Instance.OnNotificationReceived -= NotificationReceived;
        CrossPushNotification.Instance.OnNotificonReceivedWhileForegroundationReceived -= NotificationInForegroundReceived;
    }

    public override void ViewDestroy(bool viewFinishing = true)
    {
        //Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Unsubscribe<NotificationMessage>(_token);
        CrossPushNotification.Instance.OnNotificationReceived -= NotificationReceived;
        CrossPushNotification.Instance.OnNotificonReceivedWhileForegroundationReceived -= NotificationInForegroundReceived;
        base.ViewDestroy(viewFinishing);
    }
```

But these event handlers are null when app comes from background because the view didn't appear yet. I can't attach the handler of the events in the constructor because then I can't remove it when the view is disappeared. Only the current view model should handle the event and navigate to my desired viewmodel.

I've also tried the MvxMessenger plugin without success.

So my question is, how can I properly notify my view models that a push notification came when app was in background?